# Do any browsers support the form attribute on input elements?

Tags: forms, html

The HTML5 spec allows [form-associated elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/forms.html#form-associated-element) to refer to their [associated `<form>` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fae-form) via the `[form]` attribute. Do any browsers support this natively?

Comment: [Can I Use: Form Attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See:

- http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/
- http://swatelier.info/at/forms/HTML5attrib.asp

The `form` attribute is supported since Firefox 4, Opera 9.5, Safari 5.1 and Chrome 10, but not on IE yet.

Here's a test page:

http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/html5-form-attribute/

Answer (score 3):

> Opera 9.5+, Safari 5.1+, Firefox 4+, Chrome 10+

Answer (score 0):

Chrome v25 does not seem to recognize the use of the form attribute.  A form that contains an element that has "form='xxx'" in it will not show up in that form's submitted content if the form name/id does not match the value of the form attrib.  Also if the form attrib contains two form names, it will not show up at all, even if one of the names matches the form's name/id.  Strange behavior.

Comment: Would you mind wording your answer in a more readable way? Possibly adding information about other browsers?

Comment: If I'm reading you right, I think that's the intended behaviour.