# Using buttonset on radios with html5 Form Attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, radio-button, radio-group

I have multple pages using the same layout as below, the only thing that is different about this page, is that I have to have multiple forms on the same page, so I'm using the `form=""` html5 attribute.

```
<form id="edit" name="edit"></form>
<label>STATUS</label>
<div class="radios padTop" id="status">
    <label class="inline true" for="active">ACTIVE</label>
    <input type="radio" name="status" form="edit" value="1" id="active" />
    <label class="inline false" for="inactive">INACTIVE</label>
    <input type="radio" form="edit" name="status" value="0" id="inactive" checked="checked" />';
</div>
```

The page renders correctly on page load:

[image]

However If I'm to click on 'Active', it doesn't remove the class `'ui-state-active'` on the inactive radio button like it does on my other pages and renders like this:

[image]

I have tried calling `$('.radios').buttonset('refresh')` and it still doesn't update.

I'm using `jQuery v2.0.0` and `jQuery UI v1.10.2`

I know that this is failing because of the form attribute, if I wrap the radio div inside the form the field works fine! I'm assuming that Jquery UI doesn't allow for the form attribute?

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/3D4Ce/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms are containers, or at least they have been. Not sure if that changed in html 5. See if this helps.

```
<form id="edit" name="edit">
    <label>STATUS</label>
    <div class="radios padTop" id="status">
        <label class="inline true" for="active">ACTIVE</label>
       <input type="radio" name="status" form="edit" value="1" id="active" />
       <label class="inline false" for="inactive">INACTIVE</label>
       <input type="radio" form="edit" name="status" value="0" id="inactive"
          checked="checked" />';
   </div>
</form>
```

*UPDATED* You could add a click event to handle this yourself

```
<script>
   $('input:radio').click(function() {
       $('input[name='+$(this).attr('name')+']:not(:checked)').each(function() {
          $('label[for='+this.id+']')
           .removeClass('ui-state-active');
       });
   });
</script>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/753pu/

Comment: @ShannonHochkins My bad. Still I would find it a bit amazing if jQuery UI were demanding a wrapping form tag. From what you are displaying, it looks as if jQuery is styling the elements into a buttonset correctly.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins See the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143140/do-any-browsers-support-the-form-attribute-on-input-elements to confirm if your browser fully supports the form tag. If it does, then you'll need to review the source for jQuery UI buttonset.Look for how it binds the click event to see if it references a parent form tag.

Comment: I'm using the newest chrome it's not a support issue @B2k

Comment: I have added a fiddle example to show you that it's jquery that doesn't work with this layout.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins Fixed, using the update from my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/3D4Ce/4/

Comment: Thankyou, it will do for now! Bit dodge but it works :) I've submitted the bug to jquery

Comment: @ShannonHochkins One small refinement, to target only radio buttons included in a button set. http://jsfiddle.net/3D4Ce/5/

Comment: You could also only bind the event to un created buttonsets too `$('.radios:not(.ui-buttonset)').buttonset()`

Comment: @ShannonHochkins You might consider adding icons to your button sets. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFWbdxicvK0 for a great analysis of button usability. This site adds checkmark icons to the button sets. http://aq3.processmyquote.com/UsAgencies/en/Home/Prefill?ZipCode=60610