# send data from select when option is selected with submit button

Tags: html

I have a select dropdown

```
<select form="orderby" name="order" >
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="rating">Rating</option>
    <option value="likes">Popularity</option>
    <option value="time">Time</option>
    <option value="cost">Cost</option>
</select>
<select form="orderby" name="sort" >
    <option value="ASC">Ascending</option>
        <option value="DESC">Descending</option>
</select>
<form style="display:inline-block" id="orderby" action="frapnel2.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo $city;?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

What happens is after selecting the option and hitting go I call my page with the new values and what I have to but I want to get rid of pressing go every time. How do I do that?

Comment: as i understan you want to charge automatically the information when the user changes the values of your select values, isn't it??try to use jquery then...

Comment: Yeap that's it. How do I use jquery for that? Can I have an example?

Comment: use [onchange event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) and submit your form from this event : [submit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add an `onchange` attribute to the `<select>` element that submits the form. Eg:

```
<select form="orderby" name="order" onchange="form.submit()">
```

**Note**:

- There should always be a submit button (on a public web page), even if you don't think you need one. You cannot know with certainty that the users browser will execute your scripts, or execute them correctly. There are few things that are more annoying than web forms that cannot be submitted.
- The `form=...` attribute is new in HTML5. [Some say](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10143140) it is not supported by IE. Your best bet is probably to put the form elements inside a `<form>`.